# The rebels [could / were able to] draw on the support of over 20,000 soldiers

Tags: word-choice, could, can-vs-be-able

I don't understand why both are correct answers.
Isn't it supposed to use [be able to] rather than [could] if the situation is a specific event in a specific moment, which I think is this case? 
For example, be able to is correct, not could, in this sentence : We [were able to] finish the football match before it started snowing too heavily.

By the way, this is a question from Advanced grammar in use. 
Please let me know what I am missing. Thank you.

Comment: Who told you that you must use _be able to_ rather than _can/could_ if it’s a specific situation in a specific moment? There is no such rule. _Can/could_ fulfils several epistemic roles relating mainly to ability, habituality, evidentiality and permission; this makes it ambiguous in many cases. _Be able to_ is less ambiguous, since it deals exclusively with ability, so of course there are cases where _be able to_ is generally preferred or more common – but there is no rule saying that it must be used in any situation, except with untensed forms (which _can/could_ does not possess).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the rebels had convinced 20k soldiers that their cause was a noble one but told them to not say anything and just continue to pretend to be loyal soldiers.  In this case, *the rebels **could** draw on the support of over 20,000 soldiers*, but choose not to.

Later, perhaps, during a battle which they were losing, *the rebels **were able to** draw on the support of over 20,000 soldiers* and thus emerged victorious.

Answer (score 0):

Could is a **conditional** and **past tense** indicator of can so therefore,

> Could means both "were able to" and "would be able to"

I believe your confusion is involving the unique dual tense usage of this verb.